# Bottob Tab top border is not visible on android

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using Bottom Tab of react navigation and I am using `borderWidth:1` and `elevation:0` in `tabBarStyle` property of `Tab.Navigator`. How can I make top border visible?

[image: Bottom Tab]

Comment: I think there is a tab bar height you will need to adjust the top of your component is going out of the View: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbarstyle

Comment: It didnt work. It is same issue with Drawer header too but with bottom border.